# Beamer, beamerposter, blocks, and multicols

Tags: beamer, multicol, beamerposter

I'm trying to use Beamer (also Beamerposter) with `multicols`. But unfortunately, when I insert a block, the block spans the full width of the page rather than just the column that it's in. Compare this to the `columns` environment, where the block only spans the column that it's defined within. However, I like `multicols` because I like how it automatically wraps text to the next column, whereas with `columns` I have to explicitly specify what goes in the first column and what in the second. Is there a way around this -- can I use Beamer blocks within the `multicols` environment?

Below is an example of what happens, with the code provided at the bottom.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\sometext}{
  Here is a bunch of text repeated over and over and over again.
  Here is a bunch of text repeated over and over and over again.
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{With columns}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
                \textbf{Here the example block only spans one column.}
                \begin{example}
                    \sometext
                \end{example}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
                \sometext
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{With multicols}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \textbf{Here, the example block spans both columns.}
            \begin{example}
                \sometext
            \end{example}
            \sometext
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `multicols` with beamer. They lack many of the nice features of beamer columns to customise alignments and overlays.

If you really must use them, you can work around the problem with a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{With multicols}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \textbf{Here, the example block spans both columns.}
            \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
            \begin{example}
               \lipsum[2][1-3]
            \end{example}
            \smallskip
            \end{minipage}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could load the tcolorbox inner beamer theme, which replaces normal beamer blocks with tcolorboxes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{With multicols}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \textbf{Here, the example block spans both columns.}
            \begin{example}
               \lipsum[2][1-3]
            \end{example}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! The `tcolorbox` example does not work for me (I am using Overleaf). Overleaf is happy with `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`, but it throws an error when calling `\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}`. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @Joe Overleaf uses an old version of texlive which does not yet have the tcolorbox inner theme. You can manually upload the .sty file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samcarter/beamertheme-tcolorbox/main/beamerinnerthemetcolorbox.sty